# Display a set of collections that include a product with a specific tag

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to set up a page which displays a list of collections, like the general 'list-collections.liquid', but only display collections that contain products with a certain product tag.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
 {% assign var = 'test' %}
    {% assign tagtrue = false %}
    {% for collection in collections %}
      {% unless collection.handle == 'frontpage' %}
      {% for product in collection.products %}
      {% for tag in product.tags %}
        {% if tag contains var %}
          {% assign tagtrue = true %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
      {% if tagtrue == true %}
        <a href="{{ collection.url }}" title="{{ 'collections.general.link_title' | t: title: title }}">
          {% if collection.image != blank %}
            {{ collection | img_url: '480x480' | img_tag: collection.title }}
          {% elsif collection.products.first != blank %}
            {{ collection.products.first | img_url: '480x480' | img_tag: collection.title }}
          {% else %}
            {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
            {{ 'collection-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg placeholder-svg--small' }}
          {% endif %}
        </a>

        <p>
          <a href="{{ collection.url }}" title="{{ 'collections.general.link_title' | t: title: title }}">{{ collection.title }}</a>
        </p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But when I go to the collection list page this still returns all collections. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation, you'll find that a product has a special method on it labelled **collections**. In other words, that gives you a list of all the collections the product belongs to.

So now on to your question. You ask how you can display a list of collections, but only the ones that contain products with a specific tag. OK... fair enough. You will blow speed out the window, but a simple algorithm might be:

- create a collection of products with tag **foomanchu**
- iterate the products in that collection, and use the product.collections
- for each collection listed, add it to a list if it has not already been added

Once done that loop, you have the answer. A list of collections for products with a specific tag.

Good luck with performance on that, and remember to keep it simple. That looping is fast for a small shop with limited inventory, but if you have many thousands of skus with a tag spread out across many collections, you'll be challenged for instant rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a speed improvement over David Lazar's answer by using Shopify's `map` filter.

As with his answer, step 1 is to create a collection with the rule "Product contains tag" and enter the tag that you are using.

Now assuming that you have that collection object in a Liquid variable named `collection`, you would get the handles of all the collections through a simple `map` command, followed by a `uniq` command to strip out all the duplicates:

```
{% assign all_collection_handles = collection.products | map: 'collections' | map: 'handle | uniq %}
```

The `map` filter gets very specific information from the wad of objects, so it's quite a bit faster than iterating through a lot of big objects with a slew of fields you don't care about.

(Note that `uniq` only works on strings, numbers, or other simple data types, which is why we map all the way to the collections' handles)

Now you can iterate through `all_collection_handles` to do what you need to do:

```
{% for handle in all_collection_handles %}
  {% assign collection = collections[handle] %}
  <!-- Cool stuff here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Since you should have a much shorter list of collections than you do of products, this should be reasonably performant.  Be aware as always that the more heavy-lifting that you're doing in the Liquid code the more likely you'll get page-load delays, so keeping your loops short and using focused filters such as `map` whenever possible will help keep things running as fast as possible.

Note: If your page starts to suffer from extreme page-load lag, you may want to skip doing this as part of the page-load and just leave a placeholder element, then use Javascript to fetch the information you need and create the display you want.